# InvalidArgumentException Route not defined

Tags: laravel

i have problem with my update ,, when i am click submit on update page,, the error show like this

(1/1) InvalidArgumentException
Route [kontak] not defined.

this is my route

```
    Route::get('kontak','ProductController@index');
Route::get('kontak_create','ProductController@create');
Route::post('kontak','ProductController@store')->name('kontak.store');
Route::get('kontak_edit/{id}','ProductController@edit')->name('kontak_edit');
Route::put('kontak_edit/{id}','ProductController@update')->name('kontak_edit');
Route::delete('kontak','ProductController@destroy')->name('kontak.destroy');
```

my controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{


        // menggunakan elequent untuk menyimpan ke database
    $product = Product::where('id',$id)->first();
    $product -> namaproduct = $request->input('namaproduct');
    $product -> descriptionproduct = $request->input('descriptionproduct');
    $product -> currency = $request->input('currency');
    $product -> ukuran = $request->input('ukuran');
    $product -> warna = $request->input('warna');
    $product -> type = $request->input('type');
    $product -> stock = $request->input('stock');
    $product -> harganormal = $request->input('harganormal');
    $product -> hargadiskon = $request->input('hargadiskon');
    $product -> tanggaldibuat = $request->input('tanggaldibuat');

    $product->save();


    return redirect()->route('kontak')->with('alert-success','Data berhasil diubah!');
}
```

.
and this is my edit.blade.php

```
 @foreach($product as $produk)
        <form action="{{ action('ProductController@update', $produk->id) }}" method="post">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            {{ method_field('PUT') }}
```

...................

```
<div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-primary">Submit</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-md btn-danger">Cancel</button>
            </div>
```

when i click submit button on edit page.. yhe error show like above
?? 
whats wrong with my code ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define a route named `kontak`

Try this.

`Route::get('kontak','ProductController@index')->name('kontak');`

Comment: Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::update(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

Comment: You need to change a name `kontak_edit`  in your routes

Comment: i already change name kontak_edit like this
Route::put('kontak','ProductController@update')->name('kontak');

but still error

Comment: Oh my bad sorry. Change this block `route('ProductController@update',$produk->id` to `route('kontak_update',$produk->id)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('kontak_edit/{id}','ProductController@edit')->name('kontak_edit');
```

`Route::put('kontak_edit/{id}','ProductController@update')->name('kontak_edit');`

Your name for the Get and Put is  the same.

Comment: Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::update(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected