# Laravel: How to fix routing the index page is not defined, but the routing declared already on the controller?

Tags: php, laravel

I got confuse and I got an error, why does my routing process not work, The error gives me Route [index] not defined, but on other hand I already defined the index to HomeController, take a look at my process that I did,

**Note: I used laravel version: 5.8***

1. I create a index.blade.php
2. Add the routes to the web.php and I used this code

```php
`Route::get('/index', 'HomeController@index');
```

3. I add the public function index to the HomeController

**Web.php**

```php
    Route::get('/index', 'HomeController@index');
```

**HomeController**

```php
    public function index()
    {

        return view('index');

    }
```

**My URL:**

[image: My URL]

**Error:**

[image]

Comment: share your `URL` that you called foit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [InvalidArgumentException Route not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50509124/invalidargumentexception-route-not-defined)

Comment: Remove ```/``` in route. write route like this: ```Route::get('index', 'HomeController@index')->name('homeIndex');```. and give route in your blade file like this : ```{{ route('homeIndex') }}```.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be in your index view.

Looks like you are trying to access route using route name and you have not defined  the route name for index route.

So in web.php add `->name('index')`

`Route::get('/index', 'HomeController@index')->name('index');`

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide name of the route in your routes.

```
Route::get('/index', 'HomeController@index')->name('index');
```

You can also use the below syntax

```
Route::get('/index', [
'as' => 'index',
'uses' => 'HomeController@index'
]);
```

for more information please have a look at the docs

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#named-routes

Answer (score 0):

Try This

if you use route this way

```
Route::get('/index', 'HomeController@index');
//then your url will be
URL/index
```

**OR use this way**

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
//then your url will be
URL
```

Comment: I used that already but nothing work on both two suggestion answer.

Comment: that's my main problem I don't know why that routing is not working

Comment: which way you call url? @SoulAiker

Comment: you not given your url which call index

Comment: what do you mean url which call index?

Comment: do you mean index.blade.php?

Comment: in browser i mean

Comment: I used only localhost:8000/index for my url

Comment: i dont know but you made some mistake in your code? @SoulAiker, because its working proper

Answer (score 0):

Try with localhost/folder_name/public/index if this works for you then probably problem is with virtual host creation.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your view you are using `{{route('index')}}`.

Add `->name('index')` in the end of your route.

```
Route::get('/index', 'HomeController@index')->name('index');
```

Hope this will help.